# When I change my status, do I need to report public benefits received before October 15, 2019?

Tags: united-states, immigration, medicaid

If I was pregnant 30 months ago, do I still need to say on form I-539 that I used Medicaid during my pregnancy?

What if I answer that I didn't use Medicaid?

What does this sentence mean in the instructions for form I-539?

> NOTE: You only need to report public benefits received on or after October 15, 2019 but not any received before October 15, 2019.

Comment: Note that you actually don't need to report non-cash benefits (like Medicaid) [received before February 24, 2020](https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-8-part-g-chapter-9#S-A-8) (not October 15, 2019). The effective date of the public charge rule was pushed back due to court injunctions.

Comment: Also note that, even after February 24, 2020, only federally-funded Medicaid needs to be reported. I believe that all states that provide Medicaid or equivalent for pregnant women who don't have green cards are funded solely by the state, in which case it doesn't need to be reported.

Comment: And even if there were a federally-funded Medicaid that you received while pregnant (which I don't think there is for women without green cards, but even if), you just need to report it and also check a box in a following question that says you received it while pregnant, and it will not count for public charge purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Thirty months is two and a half years, so 30 months ago was April, 2018.  Since April 2018 is before October 15, 2019, you do not need to report your use of Medicaid in April 2018.

The note means just what it says.  I don't understand why you find it unclear, although it is certainly somewhat redundant.  I can't think of any way to clarify it other than to restate it:

- Receipt of benefits on October 14, 2019 or earlier does not need to be reported.
- Receipt of benefits on October 15, 2019 or later must be reported.